# c# Time formatting

Tags: c#

I have a time field as such: 06:30 PM.
What formatting do I need so that it shows up as 6:30 PM.
I tried:

```
     String.Format("{0:t}", data.PgTime)
```

but still getting 06:30 PM

Comment: Honestly - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `t` is the [standard format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) for "short time pattern" - so it's being formatted according to the current culture's rules. For me, it would show "18:30" because that's the appropriate format for the UK.

You can *either* stick to the rules .NET knows about, or you can use a [*custom date and time format string*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) to force a specific format, e.g.

```
string text = date.ToString("h:mm tt");
```

(Note that this is basically equivalent to `string.Format("{0:h:mm tt}", date)` but considerably simpler to read - I'd suggest only using composite formatting when you're really formatting more than one value.)

Usually that would *not* be a good idea though - it suggests that you know more about cultural rules than Windows / .NET, which is unlikely to really be the case. I'm sure you know more about how *you personally* like to format dates and times, but that's not the same as it being the standardized convention for your culture.

Comment: Jon, in string text = date.ToString(("h:mm tt"); if date is null, we will get an exception. On the otehr hand, string.Format("{0:h:mm tt}", date) will not create an exception if it is null. If you can confirm as this is what I am finding.

Comment: @NatePet: You didn't say you were trying to format a `Nullable<DateTime>`. Personally, in that case I'd explicitly handle the null instead: `string text = date == null ? "" : date.Value.ToString(...);`.

Answer (score 2):

```
String.Format("{0:h:mm tt}", data.PgTime)
```

#### See also:

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) on MSDN.